# Is there a way to conveniently export Grafana configurations, e.g. alerts, so they can be provisioned?

Tags: grafana, provisioning

I am using Grafana v8.2+ and created some (unified) alerts and such things via the very convenient web UI.

**Is there a way to export all these configurations done in the web UI, so that I can eventually store them in a git repo and provision it later on again?**

I already did this with datasources and dashboard providers, but it is rather tedious to pick together the YAML files from stackoverflow or some other sources, so I hoped for a convenient export mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

There is no export/import of the alerting rules in the unified alerting page similar to dashboards as of now which makes the provisioning process a little bit harder. This is much needed feature, please check this grafana [community page](https://community.grafana.com/t/ngalert-grafana-8-alert-feature-how-to-export-import-alerts-as-yml-json/51677).

You can use the API to export/import alert rules, there are examples on how to do that in the same community page in this [comment](https://community.grafana.com/t/ngalert-grafana-8-alert-feature-how-to-export-import-alerts-as-yml-json/51677/12) and this [comment](https://community.grafana.com/t/ngalert-grafana-8-alert-feature-how-to-export-import-alerts-as-yml-json/51677/21).

Answer (score 0):

Like @ahmed-salman said, there's a nice fix, but if you have multiple rules in a check, the code in the [second comment](https://community.grafana.com/t/ngalert-grafana-8-alert-feature-how-to-export-import-alerts-as-yml-json/51677/21) should be fixed:

```
del(.rules[0].grafana_alert.uid)
```

should be

```
del(.rules[].grafana_alert.uid)
```

So all rules will be stripped of UID.