# How to export/import Grafana Alerts?

Tags: grafana, grafana-api, grafana-alerts

I tried to export via API, Curl,grafanaalertsexporter
Every method had failed.
Is there a way to export and import the Grafana (Version:8.5 )Alert Rules to JSON files conveniently?

Comment: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/developers/http_api/alerting_provisioning/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to conveniently export Grafana configurations, e.g. alerts, so they can be provisioned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69766772/is-there-a-way-to-conveniently-export-grafana-configurations-e-g-alerts-so-th)